# How not to add row to DB if it exists

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have to entities which has `@ManyToMany` relation. If I add some data, it adds to tables of both entities, but I want data not to be added to child entity if such data exists. 
I have third table with relation between both entities. And if I add some data I want it not to be added to child entity if such data exists there but to be added to third table - the value which exists in second.

Comment: so, first check if it exists

Comment: share your code.....